# Mini displayport output not working after Windows 10 update 1709

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, external-display, displayport

Since Windows 10 Update 1709, there has been no output signal from the mini DisplayPort of my laptop.
The 2nd monitor is detected in the device manager and in the display parameters, but receives no signal. HDMI video output still works.

I have tried:

- Switching the display mode with Win+P
- Changing the resolution
- Updating/reinstalling monitor drivers
- Rolling back the Windows update
- Updating GPU drivers
- Reinstalling Intel management engine

Any thoughts on possible solutions?

Note: I have no other mini-DP devices so I am unable to check for material defficiency, but everything from the laptop to the cable and the monitor is quite recent and was working perfectly just before the update.